# Missing CSS need to be fixed

Tags: html, css

I implemented my design yesterday here: https://jsfiddle.net/8f3vLh0a/17/

It uses font awesome on its design. Now my issue here is that when i remove the old span icons w/c are image using this line of code:

```
  <span class="icon home "></span>
```

It will actually destroy spacing on the font awesome icons as seen on this version: https://jsfiddle.net/7869qLmx/1/

It must be centered on the screen. how can I do that? which CSS should I move?

here's my current JSFIDDLE Version: https://jsfiddle.net/7869qLmx/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because margin in i.fa class

```
i.fa {
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  color:white ;
  top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: -45px;
}
```

I have updated in my fiddle.

Check it out
[https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/7869qLmx/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/7869qLmx/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the margin of the i.fs class

```
i.fa {
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  color:white ;
  margin:16px 0 0 14px;

}
```

Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7869qLmx/4/

Answer (score -1):

The images are used as font. So font size is missing on body.
Add to your css code
body { font-size : 14px; }
And the size of the images will too correct.

`body {
    font-size : 14px;
}`